# Свой UI для JScrollPane

Tags: java, изображения, ui, jscrollpane, scrollbar

При создании фрейма, я создаю JScrollPane, получаю его JScrollBar и переопределяю для него свой UI `Scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(NewScrollBarUI);`

Дальше, что бы я не писал в NewScrollBarUI, его вертикальный скролл остается невидимым и не реагирует на мышь, хотя через колёсико проматывание работает.

К слову, хочу заменить все 4 элемента(increase button, decrease button, thumb, track) скроллбара, на изображения. Изображения существуют, ссылки на них действительны.

Надеюсь на помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось создать свой UI.
Вот наставления тем, кто столкнется с похожей проблемой:
Нужно создать свой класс, растягивающий (extends) `JScrollPane` и уже его создавать в своем фрейме.

В классе нужно прописать 
`<java>`publicJscrollPane() {
super() ;
this.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new ScrollBarUI());
} `</java>`

Далее нужно создать класс ScrollBarUI, растягивающий `BasicScrollBarUI`

Все. Теперь уже можно использовать @Override и писать свой UI.